# Getting the target entity attribute value (c# pluigin)

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm

My plugin is ran when a value is changed on a form.
I am trying to pass in the 'name' attribute of the target entity as a variable.
However, the name is showing as blank in my trace log.
The attribute logical name is correct and there is a value in the form.
Also, the Id is passing through OK so the target entity is working.

I tried defining 'entityName' as both var and string but neither work.

Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong below?

```cs
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
    IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
    IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
    IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

    Entity entityTarget = context.InputParameters["Target"] as Entity;
    Guid guid = entityTarget.Id;
    var entityName = entityTarget.GetAttributeValue<string>("new_name");
    tracingService.Trace("entityName = " + entityName);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When attribute `new_name` is not modified, it will not be part of the `Attributes` collection in the **"Target"** entity.

Attributes that have not been modified must be retrieved from a **pre entity image**.

```cs
Entity entityTarget = context.InputParameters["Target"] as Entity;
Entity originalEntity = context.PreEntityImages.Values.FirstOrDefault();

if (!entityTarget.TryGetAttributeValue<string>("new_name", out string entityName))
    entityName = originalEntity.GetAttributeValue<string>("new_name");

tracingService.Trace("entityName = " + entityName);
```

> Remember you need to register this pre image on the update plugin step and in the image attribute `new_name` must be selected.